# Problems mousing over variable names in iPhone debugger

Tags: iphone, debugging

I'm attempting to do some debugging in GDB for an iPhone app issue.  When I mouse over a string variable to see the contents the console goes into an infinite scroll with the text "Unable to access variable ".

Any ideas on why this might be happening?

Comment: i get this as well, is it only happening since you moved to a later version of xCode? is your configuration in Debug?

Comment: As a matter of fact... yeah.. I did upgrade XCode this past week but you are correct about the configuration.  I didn't realize it was on release.  I switched to debug and i'm back to normal.  Thanks! Post an answer instead of a comment so I can give you points.

Answer (score 5):

For future reference, there are several major causes:

- Target-level optimization settings: there should be no optimization
- Target-level strip symbols: symbols should not be stripped
- Target-level level of debugging symbols: default or all symbols should be used
- Per-file compiler flags (get-info on file, choose Debug tab): Make sure there are no optimization per-file settings as there is no way to specify in what configuration (debug or release) they should be used, so they're always used.

I go into more detail [here](http://joshua.nozzi.name/2010/09/buggered-debugger/).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and setting configuration to Debug fixed it... quite reasonable :P

Credits to @AranMulholland comment!